# react hosted on S3 having trouble using env files for Auth0 values

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, auth0

This is more of a lack of understanding on my part but I cannot seem to debug this.

I have a react app that I use Auth0 for some authentication stuff.

I recently moved my site on production from using a docket container to running from S3.  I thought this was working but its clearly not today it times out when I click login

Request URL: https://undefined/authorize?

This just times out

It works from local host and no longer says undefined it has my auth0 domain

In my react app I store that Auth0 Domain value in a .env file.  I am assuming my issue is that react in my S3 bucket does not have my .env file because gitignore.  I thought maybe at build that was somehow pulled into a build file ? So when I do npm run build does it do anything with that .env?

How do I use my .env with react running in S3

This assumes that is what my issue is it seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple issues going.

1. Cloudfront was caching my site so as I was debugging I was not viewing my latest code.  I had to invalidate cloudfront cache after each push.
2. I added my Auth0 secrets into github action secret and then used them with an env:   section in my github action.  That allowed me to use environment variables when github action performed the build.

All works now I was just tangled up for a short time.